# ios: How to send SMS in background

Tags: ios, xcode5

I know How to use **MFMessageComposeViewController** to compose message and forward the SMS and I want to send SMS in background without displaying message composer view. so If I click on button SMS will send in background without prompting to user.

There are 3rd party API's like Twilio, nexmo and tropo but i am not getting how to implement with those API's.

There is any other way to send SMS in background?

Comment: Just think for a minute why sending an SMS without user interaction might have been prevented by Apple. Particularly: Fraud and bill-shock

Answer (score 5):

Using the standard API's you can only send an SMS with user interaction.

Comment: but i want to know how to send SMS without user interaction?? is there any API's or method?

Comment: There isn't a way using the standard API's.  If you're looking for a 3rd party recommendation, that's beyond the scope of SO.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send SMS or e-mail without user interaction unless there is any server interaction. If you really want to send SMS in background, send the content and reciepients to your server in background and from the server side you can send SMS to your receipients.