# Send SMS/Email automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, email, sms

In my app I need to send SMS and Email automatically possibly at background. Is it possible to send SMS automatically on a specific number and email on a specific email address?

Comment: This is not possible in the official iOS SDK. Apple will reject if you tried this, unless you use your own SMS provider and E-mail services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send SMS or email using user's phone number/email on background. 
User has to approve each SMS or email.

However you can use your own server to send SMS or Email.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send SMS or e-mail without user interaction unless there is any server interaction.
But using the standard API's you can only send an SMS with user interaction. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256578/ios-how-to-send-sms-in-background)

And if you want to send SMS with user interaction then try using `MessageUIframework` which provides specialized view controller for developers to present standard interface for composing SMS text message within apps.

For more details [refer this site](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from your number then the answer is no, it is not possible. Unless you add your own SMS gate (if you are looking for something like facebook authorization sms) then it is.